# How can I permanently store commands in the Python REPL/prompt?

Tags: python, django, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a way to store commands in Python?

For example, to store a bash command I can put:

```
# in .bash_profile
alias myproject="cd /path/to/my/project"

$ project
```

Is there a way to store a command, for example something like this:

```
'store' profile="from userprofile.models import Profile"

>>> profile
```

which will work in the Python command prompt whenever/wherever it is opened? Thank you.

Comment: (If this is your only use case, you might have a look at the `shell_plus` command from [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Bash, I'm assuming you are defining this aliases in `.profile`, `.bash_rc` or a similar file. In that file, add the line

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.python_rc.py
```

This will allow you to create a `.python_rc.py` file that is included whenever you start a session in the Python prompt/REPL. (It will not be included when running Python scripts, becasue it could be disruptive to do so.)

Inside that file, you could [define a function](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) for the command you want to save. In your case what you're doing is actually a touch more complicated than it seems, so you'd need to use a few more lines:

```
def profile():
    global Profile
    import sys
    if "path/to/your/project" not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append("path/to/your/project")
    from userprofile.models import Profile
```

After doing this, you'll be able to call `profile()` to import `Profile` in the Python prompt.

Comment: Modules aren't imported "inside a function". It's true that the name of the module is only bound within the current scope, but there's nothing stopping a function from adding the name to `globals`.

Comment: @Wooble: I've so avoided using `global` that I forgot it was possible. Good idea, added.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using [IPython](http://ipython.org/), it's superior to the standard interpreter in a lot of ways, and in this particular case you can take advantage of it's ability to save macros:

```
In [1]: from userprofile.models import Profile

In [2]: macro profile 1 # profile being the name of the macro, 1 being the line to use
Macro `profile` created. To execute, type its name (without quotes).
=== Macro contents: ===
from userprofile.models import Profile

In [3]: profile # you can now use your macro
```

Macros can also span multiple lines, `macro some_macro 11 13` would be a valid multiline macro. Django's `manage.py shell` command will automatically use IPython if it's available.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda.

Write your "profile" as a script and save it somewhere.

Create a shell script that executes the Python interpreter like this:

```
python -i myprofile.py
```

When you execute the shell script it will execute the file `myprofile.py` and start the interpreter afterwards.

So if you had a file `myprofile.py`:

```
def do_stuff(x):
    print(x)
```

And ran your shell script "shortcut", you could do:

```
>>> do_stuff(1)
1
```

Comment: Seems I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Actually I don't think this is a bad answer to the question. This is better than what he asked for -- I doubt he really _always_ wants those aliases, it just seems like it right now.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't use exec, it's bad and wrong

However, I think you need it to do what you want.

1. Create a Python script. Add lines to it like

   ```
   # pythonprofile.py
   profile = "from userprofile.models import Profile"
   ```
2. Create a `PYTHONSTARTUP` environmental variable pointing to the script. This will cause the code to be executed in the interpreter when it starts up.
3. Then to actually use the command do

   ```
   exec(profile) # Don't ever do this with code you don't trust.
   ```

This executes the code contained in the string `profile` in the current scope. `exec` is dangerous, so be careful doing this.

**Edit:** @Jeremy's solution is good, but it requires you to write more code per alias than this method; either one works.